# Mounted Devices History

Tags: usb, mount, devices, media

Does Ubuntu keep the history of the devices that were mounted (i.e. USB devices, external drives etc...). If this is the case where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Insertion of a USB storage device will generate a message in `/var/log/dmesg`, as will subsequently removing it. However, this doesn't tell you much (eg, nothing about whether any files were transferred).